# using ConfigurationProperties in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration

I'm trying to use a `ConfigurationProperties` class to load my properties values. Everything works fine, but with the default `application.properties` file.

I need to use another file, say `app-1.properties`. How can I change that in my code below. I mean that in my application I will use the defaul property file and my custom property file.

My question is also about changing the path to this file and not only the name of the file.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.profs")
@Component
public class ProfsProperties {

    private String network ;

    private String database;

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public String getNetwork() {
        return network;
    }

    public void setDatabase( String database ) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public void setNetwork( String network ) {
        this.network = network;
    }
}
```

The class where i use this object

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
public class questions {

    @Autowired
    private ProfsProperties profsProperties;
}
```

My app-1.properties file

```
spring.profs.database = Arnaud
spring.profs.network = Bagna
```

I want to know also if using `@Configuration` with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is mandatory?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot - maybe this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@PropertySource` annotation or use locations in `@ConfigurationProperties` .

Example:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:abc.properties")
```

Or

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:abc.properties", prefix = "info")
```

Comment: Please check answer now

Comment: there is no location attribute in the ConfigurationProperties annotation. Have you checked your anwser?